# Add Multi String value to the registry

Tags: vbscript, registry

This code is part of a bigger application. It is designed to add anew Multi String value to the registry. I have searched all over the net and cannot get a solution to work.

I can do this with a DOS command but cannot seem to do it with VBScript.

This is the VBScrip I have found which supposedly works.

```
' Create a MultiString Value in the registry.
    Const HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE = &H80000002
    strComputer = "."

    Set oReg=GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & _ 
        strComputer & "\root\default:StdRegProv")

    strKeyPath = "SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\WebClient\Parameters"
    strValueName = "AuthForwardServerList"
    arrStringValues = Array("*.server1.com", "*.server2.com")

    oReg.SetMultiStringValue HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,strKeyPath, _
    strValueName,arrStringValues
```

Thanks In advance.

Comment: And, where is the problem? what the problem is?

Answer (score 0):

You need to run your script as administrator.

If you check the `SetMultiStringValue` return value like this:

```
res = oReg.SetMultiStringValue(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, strKeyPath, strValueName, arrStringValues)
WScript.Echo res
```

you get 5 in non-elevated mode, meaning "Access is denied" (see [System Error Codes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681382%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in MSDN).