# Invalid Parameter error when setting a registry multiStringValue using vbscript

Tags: vbscript

This is in reference to an [existing question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36184745/692942) I previously asked but same conditions are not working when doing another sub. All variables below are defined correct and as strings. I am getting error when setting values on this line:

```
objReg.setMultiStringValue HKCU,IE_Main,mStrSecStartPages,allURLs
```

The code is below;

```
return = objReg.getMultiStringValue (HKCU,IE_Main,mStrSecStartPages,multiStringValues)
'If values found in Secondary Start Pages
If return=0 Then

    ReDim allURLs(0)
            'Read all values and only store non intranet values to array
    For Each itemname In multiStringValues
        If itemname <> strFunctionIntranet1 And itemname <> strFunctionIntranet2 And itemname <> strFunctionIntranet3 And itemname <> strFunctionIntranet4 Then
            ReDim Preserve allURLs(UBound(allURLs)+1)
            allURLs(UBound(allURLs)) = itemname
        End If
    Next
            'Remove current key holding existing values
    objReg.DeleteValue HKCU,IE_Main,mStrSecStartPages
            'Set new values based on values read and user's intranet

    if UBound(allURLs)>=0 Then
    wscript.echo "in setting"
        objReg.setMultiStringValue HKCU,IE_Main,mStrSecStartPages,allURLs
    End If
    wscript.echo "out setting"

End If
```

Comment: Silly question but have debugged the `allURLs` array to make sure it is passing the correct values? A simple `For` loop and `WScript.Echo` would do the trick.

Comment: It might also have something to do with using a dynamic array, seems silly but can't test my theory at the moment. You could try using [this example from a similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23603499/692942) that uses the `Array(..., ...)` form. If that works you might find building up a delimited string then using `Split()` to split the string into an Array using said delimiter works better.

Comment: I'm willing to bet though that the `allURLs` array contains an empty element which is causing the error, see [this similar problem](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/scriptcenter/en-US/4f33d0cc-5985-497b-a5a3-6375f9290c41/adding-entries-to-reserved-ports-through-vbscript-setmultistringvalue-from-dynamic-array?forum=ITCG). Actually looking at the code that is exactly what's happening, you `ReDim(0)` then in your loop `ReDim Preserve allURLs(UBound(allURLs) + 1)` without ever setting the first element to a value.

Comment: Thanks for feedback Lankymart. That is why I have a if condition to not set value if array is not >=0 and when I do the manual check to make user that array is not empty, it does have all either one or more values yet going into this If condition it just errors out. I will check out the link you provided. Thanks.

Comment: In which case you are not doing what you expect. `allURLs` is already built by the time you do the `If UBound(allURLs) >= 0 Then` That doesn't stop the array being initialised with a blank / empty element. You should check if the first element is empty and populate it before calling `ReDim Preserve` to expand the array.

Comment: @Lank hmm good point.. just having trouble working it as a code. I tested fine when some URLs are matching but when no URLs are being stored in array, that is when the error comes up. Can you please suggest a liner to check for empty array than 'if UBound(allURLs)>=0 Then'  ?

Comment: How did you get on, were any of the suggestions helpful?

Answer (score 0):

Problem is even if there isn't any values in the REG_MULTI_SZ value you will still get an empty Array returned, which means when you then loop through the array and dynamically expand it using

```
ReDim Preserve allURLs(UBound(allURLs)+1)
```

You will always have a blank element in the first position in the array which when passed to

```
objReg.setMultiStringValue HKCU,IE_Main,mStrSecStartPages,allURLs
```

if it isn't the only element you will get

> SWbemObjectEx: Invalid parameter

Here is some testing I did to prove this

```
Option Explicit
Const HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE = &H80000002

Dim oReg
Dim strKeyPath, strValueName, arrStringValues
Dim strComputer: strComputer = "."

Set oReg=GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & _ 
    strComputer & "\root\default:StdRegProv")

strKeyPath = "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main"
strValueName = "Default_Secondary_Page_URL"

Dim rtn
rtn = oReg.GetMultiStringValue(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, strKeyPath, strValueName, arrStringValues)

Dim i
If rtn = 0 Then
  If IsArray(arrStringValues) Then
    For i = 0 To UBound(arrStringValues)
      WScript.Echo "arrStringValues(" & i & ") = " & arrStringValues(i)
    Next
  Else
    WScript.Echo "Not Array"
  End If
Else
  WScript.Echo "Failed to GetMultiStringValue - Return (" & rtn & ")"
End If

rtn = oReg.SetMultiStringValue(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,strKeyPath,strValueName,arrStringValues)
WScript.Echo "SetMultiStringValue - Return (" & rtn & ")"
```

Output:

```
arrStringValues(0) =
SetMultiStringValue - Return (0)
```

Adding the following line to create two blank elements under the `IsArray()` check

```
ReDim Preserve arrStringValues(UBound(arrStringValues) + 1)
```

Output:

```
arrStringValues(0) =
arrStringValues(1) =
test36.vbs(31, 1) SWbemObjectEx: Invalid parameter
```

So `SetMultiSringValue()` will accept an Array that contains an empty element if it is the only element in the array, the minute you try to add more you will get the error as described above.

---

#### In relation to the original code

To stop creating the extra blank element at the beginning you could switch to using a `For` instead of a `For Each` that way you can tell the loop to only call

```
ReDim Preserve allURLs(UBound(allURLs)+1)
```

when the index of the Array is greater then 0

```
For i = 0 To UBound(multiStringValues)
  itemname = multiStringValues(i)
  If itemname <> strFunctionIntranet1 And itemname <> strFunctionIntranet2 And itemname <> strFunctionIntranet3 And itemname <> strFunctionIntranet4 Then
    'Only expand if we have more then 1 value in multiStringValues
    If i > 0 Then ReDim Preserve allURLs(UBound(allURLs)+1)
    allURLs(UBound(allURLs)) = itemname
  End If
Next
```

You can do this with a `For Each` of course but you would have to track the Array index manually using another variable, which in my opinion when you have `For` already seems pointless.